# Replicate Base R Operation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replicate a set of operations using dplyr and for some reason my attempt is not achieving the same results.  My question is two things: 1.Why is the dplyr version I wrote not resulting in same result as the base operation and 2. what is the clearest dplyr (piping) implementation.  First here is some sample data that is a smaller scale of my own problem:

```
abc <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 5, 6), b = rnorm(100, 2, 3), c = rnorm(100, 0, 5), d = rnorm(100, 50, 3))
rand <- sample(c(1:100), 100, replace = F)
e <- 5
f <- 50
```

The following is the case in base R.

```
# Case 1 
abc.2 <- abc[rand,][(rand <= f) | (abc[rand, "a"] < e),]
```

This is my attempt at using dplyr, but the result of abc.3 is different from abc.2

```
# Case 2

abc.3 <- abc[rand,]
abc.3 <- abc.3 %>% filter(d >= f | d < e)
```

What is going on here?!?

Comment: Your base example doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: it does, I just ran it and subsets the data correctly.

Comment: How? `abc[d, "a"]` There is no `d` object except `abc$d`.

Comment: i edited it.  It should be abc[rand, "a"].  Was a typo

Comment: as when abc is ordered using rand keep rows that are less than e.

Comment: The base r version likely produces unintended  results. Your ```rows``` is based on the original df but you already subsetted it with the ```rand```. So what may have been the 10th row in the original could be the 5th or really, anything.

Comment: just revised the base case.

Comment: Now they just seem like different conditions. ```rand``` is not the same thing as ```abc$d```,  right?

Comment: haha sorry yeah you're right.  I guess the better question is, how would I write the base case in dplyr?

Comment: I thought I would just arrange by rand, and then replicate the conditions, but it seems to result in a different number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `dplyr` version would be using `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
abc. 3 <- abc %>% slice(rand[(rand <= f) | (a[rand] < e)])
```

We can compare the outputs

```
head(abc.2)
#            a          b           c        d
#5   4.1933216 1.89493799   0.1185014 50.17590
#59 -0.8447520 0.02859712  -8.5168739 49.04809
#32 12.9969641 5.17795376  -6.0270349 50.63730
#52 -0.5149191 4.01784805   0.8158744 50.88895
#28  7.4209741 2.71737567  -0.7756451 48.84768
#37 11.9426428 3.67445186 -10.7043711 49.88126

head(abc.3)
#           a          b           c        d
#1  4.1933216 1.89493799   0.1185014 50.17590
#2 -0.8447520 0.02859712  -8.5168739 49.04809
#3 12.9969641 5.17795376  -6.0270349 50.63730
#4 -0.5149191 4.01784805   0.8158744 50.88895
#5  7.4209741 2.71737567  -0.7756451 48.84768
#6 11.9426428 3.67445186 -10.7043711 49.88126

tail(abc.2)
#            a           b          c        d
#43  1.2259801 -0.09873229  3.4330413 54.19566
#10 12.5498938  3.03150006  7.2630499 50.08077
#49 -2.5949440 -1.65535917  7.6826515 46.42876
#80 -0.1063651 -0.81405361 -0.5607432 51.30927
#18  0.8502235  3.22688781 -3.4557019 53.39594
#22  1.8523659  7.89332620 -3.3389127 47.00231

tail(abc.3)
#            a           b          c        d
#73  1.2259801 -0.09873229  3.4330413 54.19566
#74 12.5498938  3.03150006  7.2630499 50.08077
#75 -2.5949440 -1.65535917  7.6826515 46.42876
#76 -0.1063651 -0.81405361 -0.5607432 51.30927
#77  0.8502235  3.22688781 -3.4557019 53.39594
#78  1.8523659  7.89332620 -3.3389127 47.00231
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using `d` in the `dplyr` solution but not in `base`
and your use of `(abc[rand, "a"] < e)` is the major difference as in `dplyr` solution you can just use `a < e`. Below I have just tried to recreate your `base r` solution in `dplyr`. And it seems to work

The row id is different though due to `dplyr` processing of the data frame

```
abc <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 5, 6), b = rnorm(100, 2, 3), c = rnorm(100, 0, 5), d = rnorm(100, 50, 3))
rand <- sample(c(1:100), 100, replace = F)
e <- 5
f <- 50

abc.2 <- abc[rand,][(rand <= f) | (abc[rand, "a"] < e),]

abc.3 <- abc[rand,]
abc.3 <- abc.3 %>% filter(rand <= f | a < e)


> all.equal(abc.2$a, abc.3$a)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(abc.2$b, abc.3$b)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(abc.2$c, abc.3$c)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(abc.2$d, abc.3$d)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(abc.2, abc.3)
[1] "Attributes: < Component “row.names”: Mean relative difference: 0.7186996 >"
```